# Reading complete line in 'for' loop with spaces, tabs with multiple input files

Tags: linux, bash, command, sh

I have seen articles of ***'for'*** loop. It splits on the occurance of whitespace like space, tab, or newline. To get ride of that issue i have following extra line of command:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

But when i try to solve the above scenario on following details (i have two files: ***'input1.txt'*** and ***'input.txt'*** on my current directory):

BASH command:

```
bash script.sh 'input*'
```

Below is ***'for'*** loop block in script.sh

```
for line in $(cat $1)
...
...
done;
```

I got following error on execution:

```
cat: input1.txt input.txt*: No such file or directory
```

**Note:** I want to **cat** both files ***input1.txt*** and ***input.txt***

Comment: Reading from files: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: That error message was not generated by the commands in your message. Please make a more accurate problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

By resetting `$IFS`, you disable the word-splitting that would cause the expansion of the pattern in `$1` to be treated as separate file names. This is another reason to do this the *right* way. But first, let's say you really want to pass a pattern to your script, rather than just use `bash script.sh input*` to have the shell expand the pattern to list of files for your script. Then your loop should be something like

```
cat $1 | while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
done
```

However, this won't work if any of the matching files themselves have whitespace in their names; with `input a.txt` and `input b.txt`, `$1` will expand to *4* words `input`, `a.txt`, `input`, and `b.txt`. Instead, you should really let the shell do the expansion and pass each matching file as a separate argument:

```
bash script.sh input*
```

and in your script:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        ...
    done < "$f"
done
```